# Cloning an (almost broken) HDD via dd

Tags: hard-drive, clone, dd

I have a HDD of 1TB size, that is almost broken. Sometimes I am able to boot to windows, sometimes the computer freezes at the windows boot logo and sometimes I am able to use it for a certain period of time (depending on HDD usage). In any case, the actuator arm of the HDD does clicking sounds

How are my chances that I can clone this broken HDD to a new one with `dd`. And are there any tips for special command options in `dd` suited for this kind of purpose?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can use
[ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) :

> GNU ddrescue is a data recovery tool. It copies data from one file or block device (hard disc, cdrom, etc) to another, trying to rescue the good parts first in case of read errors.
>
> Ddrescue does not write zeros to the output when it finds bad sectors in the input, and does not truncate the output file if not asked to. So, every time you run it on the same output file, it tries to fill in the gaps without wiping out the data already rescued.

So if the errors are intermediate, you could repeat the ddrescue runs until
you are successful enough.

You may not need to download the installation files, if ddrescue is a
standard package on your Linux distribution.

Comment: Ok thank you! I have read a bit about `ddrescue`. The part with the logfile that keeps track of the parts of the disk, which have not been read in the first try, is a very good feature. I am able to "try" to read these specific parts in the next try using this logfile. Thanks for this hint. I will try my luck now.